# How to implement CSS-defined images from bootstrap site in wordpress theme

Tags: images, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making my own theme from a Bootstrap 3 site that I designed. How do I best implement images that I defined in the CSS in WordPress so that I can change them later and they reference the media library?

Specifically, how do I get the background image here
[image: mockup site with background image]

to display in my wordpress theme?

[image: wordpress site with no background image]

specifically, the CSS I'm using to pull the flower image is

```
.herobox {
background: url("http://i.imgur.com/cJKKR3Q.jpg") ;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
padding-bottom:30px;
padding-top:30px;
z-index: -1;
  }
```

Obviously this isn't a viable solution if I want to be able to change the picture later from wordpress, which I'll be doing for the blog pages.

So my question is, how do I call up that background image? Do I do it with or without CSS? Where should I place the image to reference it?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You want the image to be uploaded by the theme owner or just replacing the image URL in code directly?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple solutions for defining the images ->

**`Post Thumbnails`**

While creating a new post, you can set the `Featured Image` which will automatically set the post image.

Since your image is full width, you need to set the size of the thumbnail using: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

**`Media Upload`**

1. Go to `Media` -> `Add New`. Upload your image and after upload is complete, click on `Edit`.
2. On the right hand side, copy the `File URL` in the save metabox and replace that URL in your CSS. You can view the list of all images in `Media -> Library` later on.

This solution is for editing the code directly.

**`Advanced Custom Fields`**

If there is a need to allow an image uploader directly replace this image, you need to use `Advanced Custom Fields` Image upload field and refer that field in your header.php file for the src attribute.

Comment: Or Post Thumbnails

Comment: May I know why I got some downvotes?